# MacOS-like Elastic Scrolling in GNOME?

Tags: scrolling

I just saw a differing question about scrolling in GNOME and it reminded me that there is no elastic scrolling in GNOME, which completely changes the feel of my computer.

How do you make it so when you scroll all the way to the top of the page, it continues past the limit for a second and bounces back (like in MacOS)? Right now it just stops right away but I'd like the elastic behavior.

Ubuntu 20.04

GNOME

Comment: I do not think this is a thing with Ubuntu, but rather with whatever search engine you used (ex Safari) on Mac. I am not particularly familiar with Mac, though. Does elastic scrolling work on all pages when on Mac? BTW, this page may help: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/how-to-enable-mac-os-x-like-natural.html

Comment: @Jeff Yes, this does happen on all pages when on a Mac.